# Why won't PHP retrieve my $_SESSION variables?

Tags: php

I was making a login system for a site today and had finished up all the code and everything was working fine. I pushed the changes to get and came back a few hours later to start developing again. Everything was working fine and I changed no code, then sessions stopped working. Now even very simple code will not work and I can not figure out why. Sessions were working and then just stopped for no reason.

page1.php:

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'hello world';
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

output:
Array ( [test] => hello world )

The output is just as expected. However:
page2.php

```
<?
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

output:
Array ( )

I can not figure out what the problem is, no code was changed between the time it worked, no server updates nothing. I use linode so my host did not change anything. Can anyone please tell me what to do here I have been at this for hours no suggestions help.

Comment: try adding `session_write_close();` in page1.php at the end

Comment: Are error messages turned on?

Comment: Cookies enabled ? Is the sid nicely transmited ?

Comment: I have tried session_write_close() yes they are turned on but no errors are being thrown.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` or `set_error_handler("var_dump");` before the `session_start();`

Comment: Is session_start the very first thing in your script?  If you have any output at all before it (including white space) it won't be able to send the necessary headers (unless you're using output buffering).

Comment: Both of those make it throw an error 500. The thing is not the log doesn't have errors anymore, in face the last error line was cut off half way through I don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: I changed the php.ini to Display Errors = On and for some reason errors show there but not my usual log file *shrug* it says: Warning: session_write_close(): write failed: Disk quota exceeded (122) in /home/tzdev/public_html/t.php on line 5 Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/home/tzdev/tmp) in /home/tzdev/www/page1.php on line 5

Comment: Changed the session directory to /var/tmp and increased the available disk space for that virtual server(even though it wasn't even close to max use) and it has solved the issue. Interesting since I had plenty of disk space. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the session ID.  Normally this will be done using a cookie but perhaps your browser is setup to refuse these. It can also be passed in the URL.

[Read more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)

Comment: I already verified the SID is coming across. session_id() outputs the same one both pages, just no $_SESSION vars.

Comment: Strange. Probably a simple error/issue somewhere. Make sure there is absolutely nothing before "<?php" on Page 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

this works for page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
print "{$_SESSION['test']}";
?>
```

I am not sure why, but you have to reference the session values with their keys.